# Finding distance between two points using latitude and longitude in Degree Minutes Seconds format

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude

I am working on a tool to find the distance between two points whose latitude and longitude are given. Its ok when the latitude and longitude is given in **Signed Degree Format**. But I couldn't find a way to calculate the distance when latitude and longitude is given in **Degree Minutes Seconds Format** (ex:  N 11° 14' 52').Can anybody suggest me a way to find the distance ?

Comment: Well, a Google search revealed http://www.satsig.net/degrees-minutes-seconds-calculator.htm

Comment: A second is a 1/60 of a minute, and a minute is 1/60 of a degree.  So, decimal format = Degree + Minute/60 + Second/3600.  North and East are  considered positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first convert the DMS coordinates to your degree format.

e.g. `11°14'52" = 11 + 14/60 + 52/3600 = 11.24777778 degrees`

and then continue as you did with your destance calculation that you say already works.

---

**Edit:**
Note that latitudes in the southern hemisphere and longitudes in the western hemisphere are negative. So the above formula really should be:

`sign(degrees) * (abs(degrees) + minutes/60 + seconds/3600)`

Comment: Does the original poster care about the Earth not being a perfect sphere? The standard reference work is Map Projections: A Working Manual, 1987, Snyder, John P, USGS Professional Paper: 1395. A free full-color PDF is available at http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395.